# How do I find the row where a certain value is between 2 others?

Tags: mysql

So, I have a mysql table that looks roughly like this, where the first 2 columns contain ranges.

```
1 , 5  , Value1
6 , 14 , Value2
14 , 18 , Value3
```

How can I query to find which row a certain value falls between (ie, if I have 9, it returns Value2; if I have 2, it returns Value1). This table is about 10mb big, so the more efficient, the better.

Thanks!

Comment: in 9 example its need to return value2 + value3 ?

Comment: Oops. No, hastily made example. No overlap cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  val
FROM
  table
WHERE
  table.range_min <= 9
  AND table.range_max >= 9
  /* OR 9 BETWEEN table.range_min AND table.range_max*/
```

For efficiency add an index for range_min and range_max column.

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's almost the same as madgnome's answer, however IMO a bit cleaner:

```
SELECT ... WHERE 9 BETWEEN min_value AND max_value;
```

Comment: Is there any benefit, besides cleanliness, of using BETWEEN instead of >= AND <=?

Comment: If all arguments are of the same type, the two expression are equivalent. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

```
where fielda >= 9 and fieldb <=  9
```

add a index that contain this 2 field on your table

Answer (score 0):

```
select col3 from thetable where 2 between col1 and col2
```

You'd like a combined index on `col1` and `col2` for this to perform well.